# List of fixed length that sums to a number but minimizes standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy

Im not sure if I am even asking this question the right way but here goes:

Say I want to create a python list with 20 non-zero integer elements and those elements must sum to 87.

How can I go about this to ensure that the integers chosen minimize the standard deviation of the list as a whole (not sure this is the right metric).

The following code example works, but I'm thinking there must be a better way to do this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
target = 87
target_length = 20

starter_series = pd.Series([1 for val in range(target_length)])
while True:
    current_sum = starter_series.sum()
    if current_sum==target:
        break
    if target - current_sum > 20:
        starter_series += 1
        continue
    else:
        to_be_added = target - current_sum
        index_points = np.random.choice(starter_series.index.to_list(), to_be_added, replace=False)
        starter_series.loc[index_points] += 1
```

Comment: What's your result? In my head I created `x = pd.DataFrame(np.array([4]*13+[5]*7))
x.sum()
x.describe()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple code should work:

```
n = 20
s = 87
q,r = divmod(s,n)
l = [q+1]*r + [q]*(n-r)
```

Comment: Brilliant, just brilliant